# Как использовать BroadcastReciever в качестве триггера для изменения значения отдельного TextView блока RecyclerView?

Tags: java, recyclerview, broadcast-receiver, viewholder

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

viewHolder.name_tv.setText(name_List.get(i));

viewHolder.adress_tv.setText(adress_List.get(i));

viewHolder.data_tv.setText(last_date.get(i));

holder.btn_start.setOnClickListener(() -> {
     holder.name_tv.setText("Hello);
 })
}
```

Использую такую конструкцию для замены значения `TextView` в отдельном элементе `RecyclerView` и это работает по нажатию `Button`, но при попытке использования `BroadcastReciever`'a в качестве триггера происходит замена текста во всех блоках `RecyclerView`, вместо конкретного. Подскажите, как можно решить?

Comment: О боже, зачем он здесь?
Опиши задачу, уверен на 100%, что там не нужен BroadcastReciever

Comment: @Circassian пытаюсь вывести инфу из сервиса чтоб она динамически обновлялась в блоках TextView RecycleView

Comment: @Circassian выглядит запутанно) но кажется это самый верный способ добиться желаемого?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final RAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {    
br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                // действия при получении сообщений
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                    // обновление TextView
                    String newValue = "New Data";
                    int updateIndex = 0; //номер блока RecycleView
                    name_List.set(updateIndex, newValue);
                    notifyItemChanged(updateIndex);

    }
        };
}
```